# Assign value of function pointer in struct member via a const paramater

Tags: c, pointers

The snippet below shows a struct (`ckmsgq`) with a function pointer as a member (`func`).  Then there is a function (`create_ckmsgq`) that is assigning a value to the function pointer.  However the function isn't using the usual syntax for a function pointer parameter.  It's just accepting what looks like a normal pointer to a variable, and it has the const keyword (`const void *func`).

```
struct ckmsgq {
    ...
    void (*func)(ckpool_t *, void *);
    ...
};

ckmsgq_t *create_ckmsgq(ckpool_t *ckp, const char *name, const void *func)
{
    ...
    ckmsgq->func = func;
    ...
}

static void *ckmsg_queue(void *arg) {
    ...
    ckmsgq->func(ckp, msg->data);
    ...
}
```

I think I know the answer to what will be my first question, but I would like to hear someone explain it to me (I can't find an explanation anywhere).  Why is the syntax of the 3rd function parameter for `create_ckmsgq` not `const void (*func)(ckpool_t *, void *)`?

My guess is that we are only assigning the value and not actually calling the function from this context.  However, how would I have known to do that if I where writing this code?

Other question is what is the effect of the `const` keyword on that 3rd parameter for `create_ckmsgq` if it's just a pointer to a function?

Comment: Regarding the WHY, you would have to ask the author why they would pick that specific version. It clearly offers less type safety than providing the function pointer you suggest.

Comment: Regarding `const`: It tells the compiler that wherever that pointer points to, will not be modified by that function. That is same for 2nd and 3rd parameter.

Comment: There is no guarantee that converting a function pointer value to `void *` and back to its original type would compare equal to the original function pointer value.

Comment: The function parameter type should be `void (*func)(ckpool_t *, void *)`, the same as the type of the structure member. It should not be `const void (*func)(ckpool_t *, void *)` because that has a different return type (`const void` instead of the desired `void`). Also, a return type of `const void` makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the syntax of the 3rd function parameter for create_ckmsgq not const void (*func)(ckpool_t *, void *)?

First of all, function returning `const void` doesn't make sense here, because returning `void` means function has no return value, so `const` doesn't buy anything. So why isn't the pointer declared as `void (*func)(ckpool_t *, void *)`?

Developer is making an assumption here that data pointers and function pointers are compatible. That is not guaranteed in standard C, so in order for this to work, you need a system where both pointer types are the same size and have convertible representation. And have a compiler that allows this.

If `func` is never used to carry data pointers, it's unclear what is gained by doing this.

It is troubling that there is not casting when assigning incorrect pointer to another, which would indicate that compiler warnings are either disabled, or ignored.

C standard requires that all function pointers have same representation, so more appropriate "generic" function pointer type would have been perhaps `void (*func)(void)`. You would still need to cast for conversion, but at least types would be standard compatible and little more portable.

> Other question is what is the effect of the const keyword on that 3rd parameter for create_ckmsgq if it's just a pointer to a function?

`const void *func` is a pointer to constant data with unknown type. Functions are not data, so they don't really have a concept of constness in C. If `func` is not used for actual data like it seems, and it's only used to mix incompatible pointer types, then `const` doesn't give anything here.

Answer (score 0):

your function prototype should be changed from:

```
ckmsgq_t *create_ckmsgq(
        ckpool_t *ckp,
        const char *name,
        const void *func)
{
```

to

```
ckmsgq_t *create_ckmsgq(
        ckpool_t *ckp,
        const char *name,
        void (*func)(ckpool_t *, void *))
{
```

to match the type you used to declare the struct field.  The assignment inside the function doesn't change.

The reason is that a `const void *` type is not the same as `void (*)(ckpool_t *, void*)` type.  They are both pointers, but pointers to different types.  They are not compatible.

This justifies the error message you receive, as the first is a pointer to a constant undefined type, while the second is a pointer to a function that returns nothing (void) and takes two parameters, the first being a pointer to `ckpool_t` type, and the second a pointer to undefined data.

Let me introduce a new type (for the function pointer) as:

```
typedef void(*callback_t)(ckpool_t *, void *);
```

then you can redefine your structure as:

```
struct ckmsgq {
    ...
    callback_t func;
    ...
};
```

and finally

```
ckmsgq_t *create_ckmsgq(
        ckpool_t *ckp,
        const char *name,
        callback_t func)
{
```

There's another thing.

When you declare a `void *` meaning a pointer to anything, you can use the previous declaration you used (if you had avoided the `const` that qualifies the pointer and made you lucky of being shouted by the compiler) had the pointer been `void *`, then your compiler would have said no word (but perhaps a warning about bad style of using pointers).  But this is  very bad style, and very error prone, as the compiler will allow you to pass whatever thing you can (without checking) and you could pass almost any function pointer (even a non function pointer, that will not be compatible with the one you pretend) and also you will not be able to call it (the function) inside the function.  This is a serious risk that makes me recomend to be avoided as hell.

Now it will probably be far clearer than before.